# PyTest exits with TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when collecting test cases

Tags: python, pytest, typeerror, gevent

When running `pytest --collect-only`, PyTest collects the correct tests, but terminates with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/env/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 831, in _removeHandlerRef
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/env/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 225, in _acquireLock
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/env/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 156, in acquire
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent/thread.py", line 74, in get_ident
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

From the traceback, there's no indication what went wrong in my code.

I tried upgrading related dependencies, removing some test cases, but the error persists.

Comment: It occurs when we try to call a None value as if it were a function. A common mistake is collision between package name and function name. You think you are calling a function but in fact it's the name of package. Without your code it will be difficult to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Code source for [`gevent/thread.py` around line 74](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/thread.py#L74) :

```py
def get_ident(gr=None):        # 72
    if gr is None:             # 73
        gr = getcurrent()      # 74
    return id(gr)              # 75
```

So it looks like `getcurrent` is `None`, but strangely :

```py
from gevent.hub import getcurrent    # 56
```

So it should not be those from the hub, which imports it from `greenlet`, which gets it from its C API. I can't tell what is the problem there. And I did not find similar occurrences.

Would you consider updating/reconstructing your environment ? It may solve the problem, but that's only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is this happening, other than seemingly having to make sure that `gevent`'s monkeypatching happens before `pytest` is initialised, but I found a solution in a [Github comment](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1481#issuecomment-554626603).

Create a new file – something like `pytest_green.py` – paste the code from the snippet below and run as `python -m pytest_green.py`.

```py
from gevent import monkey  # isort:skip # noqa

monkey.patch_all()  # isort:skip # noqa

import pytest  # isort:skip # noqa

pytest.main()
```